# How to interpolate expressions in ng-messages directive?

Tags: angularjs, ng-messages

Let's say that I have a form name **"signupForm"**. When I use the ng-disabled directive on a button (to disable the form in case its invalid), I use
`ng-disabled="{{formName}}.$invalid">` (formName contains the value **signupForm**)

When I inspect the button in browser, the above directive evaluates to `ng-disabled="signupForm.$invalid">`. This is perfect. The problem is that when I try to use the same expression inside of the ng-messages directive, like: `ng-messages ="{{formName}}.$error">` the expression is NOT interpolated. So if I use the directive on a div and inspect it in browser, I see it as:
`<div ng-messages="{{formName}}.$error"></div>` whereas I expect it to be shown as `<div ng-messages="signupForm.$error"></div>`. But this does not happen.

So what can be done to make the ng-messages directive interpolate the expression & show it correctly? I have tested this issue with AngularJS 1.4.7 & 1.5.0-rc.1 and the issue exists in both of them. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you check whether `ng-attr-ng-messages="{{formName}}.$error"` works?

Comment: @gustavohenke Just tried it. The result is same as previous. It does not work. Gives me this `<div ng-attr-ng-messages="{{formName}}.$error"></div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-messages=this[formName].$error`

Comment: Please explain your answer. It is currently viewed as a low quality post. Thanks!

Comment: @OmarMeky Your demo helped a lot! I made the necessary changes & it is working for me now. Thanks a ton!!! Just wanted to add that upon inspection of the element in the browser, it does not show the interpolated values. But the script works correctly as desired.

Comment: Awesome glad it helped!

Comment: @OmarMeky Hi! If you get a chance, can you please take a look at a new ngMessages related question I posted at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35137877/ngmessages-do-not-work-in-custom-directive ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ng-messages doest not allow interpolation in attribute value.
but we can pass expression to be evaluated.
***this*** in html represent current scope and it has all the information about form with validations too. you can log it and see yourself.

```
ng-messages="this[formName][fieldName].$error"   
ng-messages="this[formName].$error"
```

will work, worked for me